# Mysql total up entries for each trophy using only one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing the following fields:

id, trophy, registration

each row is a vote so for example :

```
32, 1, hk57 hxz
33, 1, hk57 hxz
34, 1, sj2 ghd
35, 2, hk57 hxz
36, 2 sj2 ghd
```

this would be 2 votes for car hk57 hxz to win trophy 1 and 1 vote for car sj2 ghd to win trophy 1. and both cars have one vote each for trophy 2

How would write a query to total up the number of votes each car has for each trophy?

Or to put it another way count the number of times the same registration is against the same trophy and display it by trophy?

Comment: Hint: `group by` and `count`.

Comment: do i have to use a sub-query here though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a way to try this right now but I'm sure you only need to `group by` trophy and `count` registers, something like:

```
SELECT trophy, registration, count(*) FROM your_table
GROUP BY registration, trophy
```

- `count(*)` means count the registers
- `group by` means 'and group them by this column'

Here you have some references:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

---

In addition to other answers, I would suggest to give alias to your count(*) if you need so!

```
SELECT registration, trophy, count(*) as votes FROM your_table
GROUP BY registration, trophy
```

So count(*) column will be called votes which is prettier

Comment: this does not produce the right kind of results. It just shows a count for each trophy not a count of individual registrations for each trophy.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't saw you needed registration too, try now!

Comment: yes but it should list the trophies with a count for each registration

Comment: no it lists registration with trophy . It should be something like Trophy 1: hk57 hxz (53) etc

Comment: I think you just need to put the SELECT part in the order you want it to be, i'll edit it right now

Comment: yai! Could you accept my comment then? I'm glad i helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT registration, COUNT(trophy) FROM table_name GROUP BY registration, trophy;
```

Comment: @user794846, do you have an error message or it isn't the result that you want?

Comment: see answer above

Comment: @user794846, basiccally the same

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a separate count for each pairing of registration and trophy, use both columns in `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT registration, trophy, COUNT(*) AS votes
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY registration, trophy
ORDER BY trophy, registration
```

Comment: It seems back to front, it should list the trophies with a count for each registration

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY` to control the order that they're displayed. It's still the same results.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be working but if I change it to show trophy as the first column it fails. So it would be: trophy, reg, votes .

Comment: The order of the columns in the `SELECT` clause doesn't make a difference. Don't change the order in `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to group by both trophy and registration.

```
SELECT count(*) as TotalVotes, trophy, registration FROM your_table 
GROUP BY trophy, registration
```

Result will be as follows:

```
    TotalVotes | trophy | registration
         2     |    1   | hk57 hxz
         1     |    1   | sj2 ghd
         1     |    2   | sj2 ghd
         1     |    2   | hk57 hxz
```